# JavaScript to replace server used for all images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

Given a static HTML file and its accompanying static CSS file that have references to a static server holding images, would it be possible to use JavaScript to prevent the page from loading all images from their src attribute and url() definition and instead replace them with another server?

Trying to do something along the lines of

```
$('body').html($('body').html().replaceAll('src.example.com', 'target.example.com'));
```

Doesn't prevent the images from being loaded at the first place. Any ideas?

Background story, in case it helps you suggest something different: I'd like my website to display images inside China from a different local Chinese server. That might help with the throttling that non-Chinese sites experience in China. Choosing a Chinese CDN for serving the whole world seems like a bad idea and relying on a service resolving DNS differently per country seems somewhat risky.

So currently we have the .com and .cn domains and want the .cn domain to be served from the same server but have its images served from a local Chinese CDN. While the website does generate dynamic pages, they are cached statically and trying to generate different pages by domain would means more effort generating the pages. That's why I thought that perhaps JavaScript could help out by replacing all images.

Comment: This would do a double-load.  The DOM doesn't exist until the server delivers it.   The actual images may not be fully downloaded, but their network call would be initiated.   CDN type directives should be handled at the server level based on geo-targeting.  You might just want to implement a CDN service for all your static content.  You can point `static.site.com` to the CDN and let it do all the work

Answer (score 1):

With a combination of tricks like using the [`base`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base)  tag and `onclick` and `onsbumit` event handlers you could achieve your objective, but I'm almost sure it isn't a nice solution.

Using a javascript at the head or the first thing in your body you could insert a base tag which would change the standard server for all resources linked by your site (forms actions, link href, stylesheets, images) requests (even the CSS ones).

Then to avoid the server change for links and forms you would have to handle click and submit events to fix the server according to the current website url or once the page is ready modify all them at once.

Does this might work? Yes, but I do believe the best solution would be change the URLs in server side or let the CDN handle the geotargeting.